# Hibernate Many-To-Many ссылка на себя. Проблема с добавлением в h2 БД. org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-jpa, h2

У меня есть Entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "planets")
public class Planet extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="related_planets",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="closing_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="opening_id")})
    private Set<Planet> openingPlanets = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="related_planets",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="opening_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="closing_id")})
    private Set<Planet> closingPlanets = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Код популяции БД:

```
Planet moon = new Planet();
Planet earth = new Planet();
Planet mars = new Planet();
mars.getOpeningPlanets().add(moon);
mars.getClosingPlanets().add(earth);

planetSDJPAService.save(mars);
planetSDJPAService.save(earth);
planetSDJPAService.save(moon);
```

В БД, в таблицу related_planets попадают правильные значения, но при этом

```
moon.getClosingPlanets()
```

по-прежнему возвращает пустое множество.
Покопавшись в StackOverflow я понял, что это не происходит автоматически, а надо добавлять самому. Я добавил следующие методы для добавления в множества:

```
public void putOpeningPlanet(Planet openingPlanet) {
    openingPlanet.closingPlanets.add(this);
    this.openingPlanets.add(openingPlanet);
}

public void putClosingPlanet(Planet closingPlanet) {
    closingPlanet.openingPlanets.add(this);
    this.closingPlanets.add(closingPlanet);
}
```

Код для популяции стал следующим:

```
Planet moon = new Planet();
Planet earth = new Planet();
Planet mars = new Planet();
mars.putOpeningPlanet(moon);
mars.putClosingPlanet(earth);

planetSDJPAService.save(mars);
planetSDJPAService.save(earth);
planetSDJPAService.save(moon);
```

Но теперь я получаю ошибку из-за вставки не уникальных значений в related_planets:

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_1 ON PUBLIC.RELATED_PLANETS(OPENING_ID, CLOSING_ID) VALUES 1"; SQL statement:
insert into related_planets (closing_id, opening_id) values (?, ?) [23505-200]

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Вопрос к дизайну. Это где такое видано, чтобы планеты содержали в себе другие планеты? Это раз. Из вашего кода увидел, что вы в список планет добавляете Луну, а она является спутником, а не планетой. Это два. Я бы на вашем месте лучше пересмотрел архитектуру системы, с ней явно не все в порядке

Comment: @FirstSin У планеты есть поле PlanetType, который является Enum и содержит типы {Звезда, Планета, Спутник ...}. Но Вы не поверите, ошибка всё равно есть ) Даже не знаю, может переименовать все объекты? )
А если серъёзно, тут связь следующая: каждый объект открывает некоторые объекты по завершению определённых действий, и соответственно может быть открыт при завершении некоторых действий с какими-то третьими объектами.
Т.е. тут не планета содержит планеты, а реализеутся связь между ними.

Comment: Я вам уже сказал, что ваша проблема - это не связи, а архитектура. Это невообразимо называть звезду или спутник планетой. Не может быть никакого PlanetType по отношению к звезде, потому что она не является планетой. Вы можете выделить абстракцию, например создав класс "Небесное Тело", который бы описывал все небесные тела. И разделить планеты, спутники, звезды и прочее на отдельные классы, которые будут наследоваться от небесного тела. Это только пример, вы можете придумать что-нибудь другое

Comment: @FirstSin При чём тут названия и архитектура? Я могу назвать как только Вы захотите, это не решит мою проблему. Если не ясен вопрос, спрашивайте - я уточню. А то что такие названия подобраны не лучшим образом я принял к сведению.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема исчезла после замены аннотаций в Entity. Код ниже:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="related_planets",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="closing_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="opening_id")})
private Set<Planet> openingPlanets = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "openingPlanets")
private Set<Planet> closingPlanets = new HashSet<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь вставить одну запись дважды. Обратите внимание на SQL, который получается:

```
mars.putOpeningPlanet(moon); // допустим moon ID = 1, mars ID = 3

public void putOpeningPlanet(Planet openingPlanet) {
    openingPlanet.closingPlanets.add(this); //INSERT INTO related_planets(opening_id, closing_id) VALUES (1, 3);
    this.openingPlanets.add(openingPlanet); //INSERT INTO related_planets(opening_id, closing_id) VALUES (1, 3);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но Вы не могли бы помочь разобраться, почему после "mars.getOpeningPlanets().add(moon);" строкой "moon.getClosingPlanets()" я не могу получить объект "mars"? В БД я вижу, что в таблицу "related_planets" добавляются id соответствующих планет. Проблема в аннотациях? Я неправильно реализовал связь?